# Opening a new Window with a Widget in GWT

Tags: gwt, new-window

Before you start shooting me down i have checked for answers and i have googled till my fingers bled but i havent been able to find a simple, concise answer. So im asking again for all those that might have this problem.

**Question:** how to open a new window with a formpanel in side.

**Context:** i have an app that lists lots of items, i want someone to edit an entry, i want a new window to open so they can edit properties then hit save. A standard thing you find in a lot of applications.

**Architecture:**
I have one client module called UI, it has a dozen classes that draw widgets and fill a main area when selected from a menu. I have a single html page called UI.html which has the  tag in the head. Thats it.

**Options Ive Seen**

1. Call **Window.Open()** but you need to define a html file. I dont have one. I can create an empty one but **how do you inject a widget in to it ?**
2. use **jsni $wnd** to create a new window and get a reference to it. But how do i **inject a form panel into it ??**
3. use a **popuppanel**. They look sucky - plus if opening a window through JS is quite simple i would expect it to be in gwt.

Maybe im miss understanding how to use GWT i dont know.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Best answer I've seen is: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/G73s5fqpYBg

Answer (score 12):

The way i got this to work is as follows:
i wrote a jsni method to open a new window

```
public static native BodyElement getBodyElement() /*-{
        var win = window.open("", "win", "width=940,height=400,status=1,resizeable=1,scrollbars=1"); // a window object
        win.document.open("text/html", "replace");
```

i added a basic body to the new window and returned the body element

```
win.document.write("<HTML><HEAD>"+css1+css2+"</HEAD><BODY><div class=\"mainpanel\"><div style=\"width: 100%; height: 54px;\"><div id=\"mainbody\"class=\"mainbody\" style=\"width: 100%;\"></div></div></div></BODY></HTML>");
        win.document.close(); 
        win.focus();
        return win.document.body;
    }-*/;
```

i then called this method from my main java method

```
BodyElement bdElement = getBodyElement();
```

I then injected my panel which has lots of widgets into the returned body element

```
SystemConfiguration config = new SystemConfiguration();             bdElement.getOwnerDocument().getElementById("mainbody").appendChild(config.getElement());
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Bogdan: Use a DialogBox.

If you can't, you `Window.open()` as you mentioned in option 1:

1. Create another GWT module, and form.html that will load it
2. `Window.open("form.html?entry=54")`
3. Have the form gwt module read from the URL, load the entry, allow it to be edited, and provide `Save` and `Cancel` buttons
4. Close the popup when `Save` or `Cancel` is clicked

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick replies. My beef with the dialogbox is it has no window frame nor the typical window look, url location etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a DialogBox?

[Example](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDialogBox)