# Create a GWT pop-out window

Tags: javascript, gwt, window

I have a GWT application and want to create a pop-out window. It is to implement a printable version of a screen of data from my application which is otherwise very messy to print from. This needs to be a new browser window, launched from my GWT application. No functionality is required on the pop-out, but I want the data to be populated via GWT.

My question is: how can I implement the contents of the browser window in GWT without having to create a new, separate GWT application for it? I don't want to have to re-write the logic to retreive the data in Javascript (this is my current best option), but I also don't want to have to make a brand new GWT application and complicate all of my builds process.

There are a few other similar questions on StackOverflow about this and usually the responses are all "Why do you want to make a new browser window? It's bad practice!" etc etc. My development team have already been through this discussion and are committed to a new browser window, so please assume that this is my only option and focus on the actual question I'm asking here.

I have read that there's ways in Javascript to populate the contents of a browser window from another window (e.g. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/writingt.htm), so perhaps this is an option, but I have no idea how to do this in GWT.

Thanks!

Comment: I found an answer on StackOverflow for my idea of writing to the other window from the originating window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167570/opening-a-new-window-with-a-widget-in-gwt#4205058. This seems to work fine, so I'm following this idea for now.

Any other suggestions are still welcome though.

Answer (score 1):

You could could create a separate URL specifically for the "printable view" of your form, and link to it using the [Anchor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) that points to that URL with a target of "_blank" as well. This could still all be managed within your current application.