# New Window in GWT, DOM, Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, gwt, dom, new-window

I'm trying to create new Window with GWT as it shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205058/898588

This works in FF, Chrome, but doesn't work in IE (IE9 in my case). I see exception in dev. mode:

**(null): DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3)**

So, this string:

```
bdElement.getOwnerDocument().getElementById("mainbody").appendChild(config.getElement());
```

throws this exception.

I've tried:

```
bdElement.appendChild(config.getElement());
```

but it was unsuccessfully.

How to make it work in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was found:

`bdElement.getFirstChildElement().setInnerHTML(config.getElement().getString());`

This works in IE, Opera, Chrome, FF

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, you only need to use setInnerHTML() instead of appendChild(), so the following piece of code will work as well in IE9 and Chrome as far as I can tell:

```
bdElement.getOwnerDocument().getElementById("mainbody").setInnerHTML(config.getElement().getString());
```